# Add an item ("---Please select---") to a combo box with a data source

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, datasource

I have a combo box with data source but I want to add an item.

I want it to look like this.

```
----Please select one---     //the item I want to add 
Tokyo                        //the items that came from the database
Osaka                        //the items that came from the database
Boston                       //the items that came from the database
Manila                       //the items that came from the database
```

How do I remedy this?

Thanks

Comment: What's the exact data source of your combobox? a `DataTable`? or anything else?

Comment: Data Source is a stored Procedure.

Comment: That's not actual data source, the data source here should be some .NET collection, list, ..., your `stored Procedure` is just called via ADO.NET to fetch the data

Comment: Then what do I need to do? How do I determine that exact data source?

Comment: **What did you assign to the `ComboBox.DataSource`**?

Comment: @DanielBarga : please share your code where you are binding `DataSource` to comboBox.

Comment: It came from a dataset. 

Data Source: teleTechInventoryDataSet
Data Member: m_Department_comboSite //stored procedure

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi where do I get that code where I bind to a comboBox? Sorry I'm not a pro :)

Comment: @DanielBarga: show your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the "please select" to the collection that you are binding to before setting the datasource, for example...

```
var countries = GetCountriesFromDatabase(); // Get countries from the database

countries.Insert(0, "----Please select one---"); // Insert your please select item

Combobox1.DataSource = countries; // Assign the datasource after inserting the item
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Combobox1.DataSource = Yourdatasource; // this is your datasource
Combobox1.Items.Add("----Please select one---");
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct - you get an ArgumentException if you try that, with the message "Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set."